# Map keyboard input to mouse input

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, input-devices

I'm looking for a software that could translate keyboard input into mouse input. For example, tap `G` and it becomes a click on a specific position of the screen.

Preferably for Linux, but it could be Windows as well.

What I want to achieve is being able to control a mobile device connected to the computer. I've got a very good software for mirroring the screen and controlling the device with a mouse, but I would like to control the screen by using the keyboard in some apps

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many programs in the Windows world which are effectively macro recorders. One would assign a sequence to the desired key. For your example, you can either "live-record" the sequence, or in some programs, hard-code the desired response. I use MacroExpress (windows, not free) which allows any hot key combination to be assigned to the macro to be executed.

The steps involved in the aforementioned program require a key assignment and a script creation. In the live-record method, recording is begun, the desired steps are performed, the recording is stopped and assigned the key.

A quick search for "macro recording software for linux" resulted in quite a few options, but my skills with linux are too limited to assess any single program.

Comment: interesting. didn't think of that. a macro could really do it. I'll try it out